# J2ME - can't shutdown output stream on client side, server hangs on waiting for data [nokia J2ME implementation]

Tags: java, sockets, java-me, nokia

My question is: is there a way to perform a socket OutputStream shutdown or it is not right/fully implemented as it should be by nokia? (J2ME nokia implementation, tested at nokia c6-00 and not closing stream, tested on emulator and works fine)

The main problem is that J2SE server application does not get the end of stream info, the condition read(buffer) == -1 is never true, tries to read from an empty stream and hangs until client is force-killed. This works with a very, very, very ugly workaround on the server side application

```
        Thread.sleep(10);//wait some time for data else you would get stuck........
        while ((count = dataInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
            if (count != BUFFER_SIZE_1024 || dataInputStream.available() == 0) { //the worlds worst condition ever written... but works
                break;
            }
            Thread.sleep(10);//wait for data input to get some data for dataInputStream.available() to return != 0 if client still sends data else you would not read all data......
        }
```

but this solution is absolutely not acceptable (i dont know something about nokia java coding, i'm missing something, or is it maybe similar to a some sort of nokia-J2ME coding standard and i should get used to it or change platform)

I can't close the client socket after sending data because server sends a response to the client after receiving and processing data.

It looks like this: J2ME client -> J2SE server (hangs on read because client does not perform a outputstream shutdown) -> J2ME

I've tried to:
close the dataOutputStream on the J2ME client - no effect
setSocketOptions (KEEPALIVE, SNDBUF and others) - no effect or errors

nothing seems to work on the target device

sorry but i'm a bit furious right now after this nonsense fight with little java.

I'have searched for the solution but non seems to work

Client code:

```
        SocketConnection socketConnection = (SocketConnection) Connector.open("socket://" + ip + ":" + port);
        int count;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE_1024];
        // client -> server
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socketConnection.openDataOutputStream());
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        while ((count = byteArrayInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
        }
        dataOutputStream.close();
        byteArrayInputStream.close();
```

Comment: Check update to my reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried the code with the same effect - on the emulator works like a charm, on the device hangs but i solved my problem as follows:

On the J2ME client before sending the 1024 byte packet I'm sending its length and its state (`IsNext` or `IsLast`) after this on the J2SE server side in a `while(true)` loop. I'm reading first the length with a `readShort`, then state with a `readByte` (I know it's better to combine it on a one short but I didn't knew if it will work and if the effort was worth it and now when it works I'm not touching this, besides it is easy to add a new state if necessarily and it works quite fast).

After this server goes in to a second nested loop [ `while (dataInputStream.available() < length) {}`  - I'll have to put here a timeout but I'll worry about that later. Also note that on J2ME `dataInputStream.available()` always returns a 0 (!) so in the J2ME client  read in this place is a `for (int i = 0; i < length... loop` reading a single byte]

When the `while(dataInputStream.available() ...` loop breaks I'm reading a block of data which length I have, and if the state is `IsLast` I break the `while(true)` loop. Works perfectly and stable.

Thanks for the advice and hope this info will help someone

Answer (score 2):

With J2SE, my advice would be to initialize Socket from the `java.nio.channels.SocketChannel` and just interrupt the blocked thread after reasonable timeout has expired.

I'm not sure which side you are trying to fix, but looks like with J2ME your only option would be to [set socket timeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29).

**EDIT**

Actually, now that you've posted client code, I see the problem. If the exception is thrown from the while loop for whatever reason, the output stream is not closed.

Here is my proposed fix for that:

```
    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

    try
    {
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                  socketConnection.openDataOutputStream()
                  );
        try
        {
            while ((count = byteArrayInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                dataOutputStream.flush();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            dataOutputStream.close();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        byteArrayInputStream.close();
    }
```

Note, that it is not strictly necessary to close ByteArrayInputStream, but the code has a habit to mutate, and some day that input stream may become something that needs explicit close.